# How to pick a different WiFi connection when one drops?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, automation

I have 2 WiFI connections available. Sometimes, the WiFi network disconnects, and when that happens, I'd like the system to automatically use the other connection.

How can I do this? I'm using a Linux system.